# Magento 2 - web setup wizard

Tags: magento2, web-setup-wizard

I'm getting the following error when I try to enter my public and private key from auth.json file in system config:

Command "show" failed: Authentication required (packages.mageworx.com): Username: The 'https://packages.mageworx.com/packages.json' URL required authentication. You must be using the interactive console to authenticate https://packages.mageworx.com could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date In Process.php line 143: The Process class relies on proc_open, which is not available on your PHP i nstallation. show [--all] [-i|--installed] [-p|--platform] [-a|--available] [-s|--self] [-N|--name-only] [-P|--path] [-t|--tree] [-l|--latest] [-o|--outdated] [--ignore IGNORE] [-m|--minor-only] [-D|--direct] [--strict] [-f|--format FORMAT] [--] [ []]

Can anybody help me with this?
Thanks in advance.